# pandas resample command keeps on running

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame looks like

```
trip_day_df.head
Out[18]: 
<bound method NDFrame.head of              
        INSERTED_UTC        VALUE
0 2017-11-03 10:30:31.430    981
1 2017-09-25 22:15:26.757   2787
2 2017-12-17 23:49:24.880   2591
3 2019-02-04 23:07:30.083  45544
4 2019-01-12 11:35:32.657    504>
```

I want to group INSERTED_UTC by rows and sum up 'VALUE'. Desired Output

```
INSERTED_UTC    VALUE
2017-12-31      6359
2018-12-31      0
2019-12-31      46048
```

```
trip_day_df.dtypes
Out[11]: 
INSERTED_UTC    datetime64[ns]
VALUE                   object

trip_day_df.iloc[0,1]
Out[12]: '981'

print(type(trip_day_df.iloc[0,1]))
<class 'str'>
```

When i run the command, to group INSERTED_UTC by Year, and sum up the value of count, the command keeps on running.

```
df_year = trip_day_df.resample('Y', on='INSERTED_UTC').sum()
```

The data originally has over a million rows, when i ran on a small size of 5 row, it gives a weird output. It's only arranging the VALUE next to each other, not summing it up

```
INSERTED_UTC    VALUE
2017-12-31  27879812591
2018-12-31  0
2019-12-31  50445544
```

Comment: What's weird about that output? You're summing strings, as you just proved yourself (`print(type(trip_day_df.iloc[0,1]))` -> 
`<class 'str'>`). What do you mean by _keeps on running_ ?

Comment: Had i realized it, i wouldn't have invested 15-20 minutes in asking the question. Only after having spent a few hours, i understood what the problem is. 
Thanks for looking into this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the feeling that the problem lies in the column 'VALUE' being a string

```
print(type(trip_day_df.iloc[0,1]))
<class 'str'>
```

I changed it's Datatype to float by

```
trip_day_df['VALUE'] = pd.to_numeric(trip_day_df['VALUE'])
```

Changed Datatype,

```
trip_day_df.dtypes
Out[44]: 
INSERTED_UTC    datetime64[ns]
VALUE                    int64
dtype: object
```

Now,

```
trip_day_df.resample('Y', on='INSERTED_UTC').sum()
Out[47]: 
              VALUE
INSERTED_UTC       
2017-12-31     6359
2018-12-31        0
2019-12-31    46048
```

Comment: How do you obtain the data? It might be possible to set the dtype at an earlier/better time.